# Does $f\circ h=g\circ h$ imply $f=g$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Is this true or false?

> If $h\colon A\to B$, $g\colon B\to C$ and $f\colon B\to C$, and for all $x\in A$, $f(h(x))=g(h(x))$, then $f=g$.

I seem to be able to prove it rather easily … or at least i think I have a proof … but I think it is false nevertheless:

$g(h(x)) = f(h(x))$

$ g = f$ by dividing by $h(x)$.

I am having trouble finding a counterexample. Can someone help? I am aware there is a duplicate question out there, but it was not answered.

Comment: HINT: What if $h$ is not surjective? Must $f$ and $g$ then agree on **all** of $B$? Note that *dividing by* $h(x)$ makes absolutely no sense at all: you’re not dealing with a product.

Comment: What do you mean by dividing by $h(x)$?

Comment: The property you're looking for is for $h$ to be an *epimorphism*, which for functions is equivalent to being *onto*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $f(x) = \sin x$, $g(x) = e^x-1$ and $h(x) = 0$. Then $f(h(x)) = g(h(x))$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- $f(x)=x$
- $g(x)=\max(0,x)$
- $h(x)=x^2$

all on the real numbers

Comment: What is $max(0,x)$?

Comment: @MichaelMathers, it's slightly odd notation for $\max\{0,x\}$, the maximum element of the set $\{0,x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal counterexample:

Let $A=\varnothing$, let $B=\{0\}$, and let $C=\{0,1\}$.

Let $h\colon A\to B$ be the empty function.

Let $f,g\colon B\to C$ with

$f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$.

Then $g\circ h=f\circ h=\varnothing$, but $f\ne g$.

Comment: To obfuscate this answer, write each set as the ordinal it represents.

Answer (score 0):

Let h be the nullset. The rest follows trivially.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My hint is much more general. Following it through will hopefully force an udnerstanding of the situation. IF people are not itnerested in the question anymore they will act accordingly.